# VHDL - Adding/Removing Pipeline Register with Generics

Tags: vhdl

Let's assume I have two processes `PROC_A` and `PROC_B`, and they share a signal between them. Let me write a dummy example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is

    port (
    clk   : in  std_logic;
    rst_n : in  std_logic;
    a     : in  std_logic;
    b     : in  std_logic;
    c     : in  std_logic;
    z_out : out std_logic);

end entity example;

architecture rtl of example is
    
    signal a_and_b  : std_logic;
    signal ab_xor_c : std_logic;
    
begin  -- architecture rtl

    z_out <= ab_xor_c;

    PROC_A : process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin  -- process PROC_A
    if rst_n = '0' then     -- asynchronous reset (active low)
        a_and_b <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then -- rising clock edge
        a_and_b <= a and b;
    end if;
    end process PROC_A;

    PROC_B : process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin  -- process PROC_B
    if rst_n = '0' then     -- asynchronous reset (active low)
        ab_xor_c <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then -- rising clock edge
        ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;
    end if;
    end process PROC_B;

end architecture rtl;
```

Now, I want to have a pipeline register between `a_and_b` and `ab_xor_c` signals, and I want to hardcode it but also enable/disable it with ease. I really want something like a `ifdef` in `C/C++`. I could think of a generic to do that but I am also open to any other method (maybe with pragmas?). I am writing an example below, I know that it is so wrong in terms of VHDL but just see it as an idea:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is

    generic (
    PIPELINE_EN : std_logic := '1');

    port (
    clk   : in  std_logic;
    rst_n : in  std_logic;
    a     : in  std_logic;
    b     : in  std_logic;
    c     : in  std_logic;
    z_out : out std_logic);

end entity example;

architecture rtl of example is
    
    signal a_and_b  : std_logic;
    signal ab_xor_c : std_logic;

    if PIPELINE_EN = '1' then
    signal pipeline_reg : std_logic;
    end if;
    
begin  -- architecture rtl

    z_out <= ab_xor_c;

    PROC_A : process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin  -- process PROC_A
    if rst_n = '0' then     -- asynchronous reset (active low)
        a_and_b <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then -- rising clock edge
        a_and_b <= a and b;
    end if;
    end process PROC_A;

    PROC_B : process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin  -- process PROC_B
    if rst_n = '0' then     -- asynchronous reset (active low)
        ab_xor_c <= '0';
        if PIPELINE_EN = '1' then
        pipeline_reg <= '0'
        end if;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then -- rising clock edge
        if PIPELINE_EN = '1' then
        pipeline_reg <= a_and_b;
        ab_xor_c <= pipeline_reg xor c;
        else
        ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;          
        end if;
    end if;
    end process PROC_B;

end architecture rtl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example has been modified to removed the register from process A and show a generic controlling the presence of the register. Additional pipeline registers could be added generically as well.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is

    generic ( PIPELINED:    BOOLEAN := TRUE);
    port (
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        rst_n:  in  std_logic;
        a:      in  std_logic;
        b:      in  std_logic;
        c:      in  std_logic;
        z_out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity example;

architecture genericly_pipelined of example is
    signal a_and_b:   std_logic;
    signal ab_xor_c:  std_logic;
begin
NO_PIPELINE:
    if not PIPELINED generate
PROC_A:
        process (a, b) is
        begin
            a_and_b <= a and b;  -- could be a concurrent statement instead
        end process;
    end generate;

GEN_PIPELINED:
    if PIPELINED generate
PIPELINED_PROC_A: 
    process (clk, rst_n) is
        begin
            if rst_n = '0' then
                a_and_b <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                a_and_b <= a and b;
            end if;
        end process;
    end generate;

PROC_B:
    process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin
        if rst_n = '0' then
            ab_xor_c <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture genericly_pipelined;
```

The granularity using a generate statement is to a concurrent statement. For purposes of changing signal names you can declare intermediary signals in the block statement elaborated by the generate statement's block declarative region. Generate statements can be nested (it's a concurrent statement) which can be used to add more pipeline registers.

A generate statement body can have a block declarative part prior to any concurrent statements in the block statement body. Concurrent statements are delineated by the reserved words **begin** and **end** followed by a semicolon when any declarations are present in the block declarative part. E.g. IEEE Std 10786-2008:

11.8 Generate statements

> if_generate_statement ::=
>     *generate_label* :
>         **if** [ *alternative_label* : ] condition **generate**
>             generate_statement_body
>         { **elsif** [ *alternative_label* : ] condition **generate**
>             generate_statement_body }
>         [ **else** [ *alternative*_label : ] **generate**
>             generate_statement_body ]
>     **end generate** [ *generate*_label ] ;
>
> generate_statement_body ::=
>         [ block_declarative_part
>     **begin** ]
>         { concurrent_statement }
>     [ **end** [ *alternative*_label ] ; ]

The generate statements in the above VHDL code have no declarations. Braces { } enclosing the item `concurrent_statement` indicate you can use the 'long form' with the **begin** and **end** reserved words with zero or more concurrent statements. You'd declare any intermediary signals used to communicate between statements found in different generate statements in the same design hierarchy. (The block statement elaborated by a generate statement is a separate declarative region.)

The BNF found in the standard's numbered sections is normative.

Note you didn't assign `z_out`.

Here's an example compatible with the OP's code:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example1 is

    generic ( PIPELINES:    natural := 1);
    port (
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        rst_n:  in  std_logic;
        a:      in  std_logic;
        b:      in  std_logic;
        c:      in  std_logic;
        z_out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity example1;

architecture generic_pipeline_stages of example1 is
    signal a_and_b:   std_logic;
    signal ab_xor_c:  std_logic;
begin
NO_PIPELINE:
    if PIPELINES = 0 generate
PROC_A:
        process (a, b) is
        begin
            a_and_b <= a and b;  -- could be a concurrent statement instead
        end process;
    end generate;

GEN_PIPELINED:
    if PIPELINES > 0 generate
        type pipeline is array (0 to PIPELINES - 1) of std_logic;
        signal pipeline_reg:  pipeline;
    begin
PIPELINED_PROC_A: 
        process (clk, rst_n) is
            begin
                if rst_n = '0' then
                    pipeline_reg <= (others => '0');
                elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                    for i in pipeline'range loop
                        if i = 0 then
                            pipeline_reg(i) <= a and b;
                        else
                            pipeline_reg(i) <= pipeline_reg(i - 1);
                        end if;
                    end loop;
                end if;
            end process;
            a_and_b <= pipeline_reg(PIPELINES - 1); -- a separate process
    end generate;

PROC_B:
    process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin
        if rst_n = '0' then
            ab_xor_c <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture generic_pipeline_stages;
```

which produces:

[image: example1_pipelines_equal2.jpg]

And shows the two clock delays using natural generic PIPELINES.

With PIPELINES = 1:

[image]

The signals a_and_b and a_xor_b show up one clock earlier. It's compatible with the first VHDL example in this answer with PIPELINED = TRUE.

Note the block declarative part contains a composite signal declaration for the pipeline stages.  A generate statement is it's own declarative region which means pipeline_reg wouldn't be visible outside the elaborated block. To access intermediary pipeline stages you'd either move the pipeline_reg declaration to the top level (example1, here) or assign signals declared in the top level assigned in the generate statement.

Comment: I overly simplify my designs or my needs, to write an example here, that's why I use a sequential process to implement a simple AND gate, just to point out the idea :) Also, I think I understand your point here, it is quite similar to what I think when I mentioned about ```ifdef```. Thanks for very clear explanation, I will try it when my design process comes to this point and I will accept this answer as a solution if it works.

Comment: Note that the shown code is not equivalent with the original code, e.g. the delay from `a` to  `ab_xor_c` is 2 clock cycles in the original code, but only 1 clock cycle in the shown code.

Comment: No the first example isn't equivalent to the original. The delay is either one or two clock cycles in the original code, while here it's either zero or one clock cycles. It wasn't clear the OP intended to have two register delays and didn't add anything to demonstrating the use of generate statements for conditionally elaborating code. You can also use a generic to specify the range of an object of an array type of pipeline register elements in the block declarative part of a generate statement, specifying how many pipeline stages. See the second example.

Answer (score 1):

Principles in the design you wrote are fine, except for the `if PIPELINE_EN = '1' then` part in the declaration of `pipeline_reg`, which should be skipped, since the synthesis will then just remove the unused `pipeline_reg`.  Also I would suggest that `PIPELINE_EN` is declared as type `boolean` instead, since that is a more obvious choice, and the `= '1'` can then be skipped in the conditions.

If for some reason you want to avoid declaration of the pipeline signal 'pipeline_reg' in the actual design, then you can declare a variable in the process, with code like below.  It is required to assign the variable after use in the code, to get a flip-flop, since it otherwise just becomes combinatorial logic.  However, such creation of flip-flops through use of variables is advised against, since it is hard to read and get right, thus error prone, and should be avoided in general.  Though here it comes:

```
PROC_B : process (clk, rst_n) is
  variable pipeline_reg_v : std_logic;  -- Results in pipeline register if PIPELINE_EN, otherwise removed by synthesis
begin  -- process PROC_B
  if rst_n = '0' then                 -- asynchronous reset (active low)
    ab_xor_c <= '0';
    if PIPELINE_EN then
      pipeline_reg_v := '0';
    end if;
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then         -- rising clock edge
    if PIPELINE_EN then
      ab_xor_c       <= pipeline_reg_v xor c;
      pipeline_reg_v := a_and_b;
    else
      ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;
    end if;
  end if;
end process PROC_B;
```

An alternative is to use the VHDL `block` construction, together with `generate`, whereby you can have `signal` declarations that are local to the block, as shown below.  Though note that the `block` construction is rarely used in VHDL, thus there is a higher risk of encountering bugs in tools.

```
PIPELINE_EN_TRUE_GENERATE : if PIPELINE_EN generate
  PIPELINE_EN_TRUE_BLOCK : block
    signal pipeline_reg : std_logic;
  begin
    PROC_B : process (clk, rst_n) is
    begin  -- process PROC_B
      if rst_n = '0' then                   -- asynchronous reset (active low)
        ab_xor_c     <= '0';
        pipeline_reg <= '0';
      elsif rising_edge(clk) then           -- rising clock edge
        pipeline_reg <= a_and_b;
        ab_xor_c     <= pipeline_reg xor c;
      end if;
    end process PROC_B;
  end block PIPELINE_EN_TRUE_BLOCK;
end generate PIPELINE_EN_TRUE_GENERATE;

PIPELINE_EN_FALSE_GENERATE : if not PIPELINE_EN generate
  PROC_B : process (clk, rst_n) is
  begin  -- process PROC_B
    if rst_n = '0' then                   -- asynchronous reset (active low)
      ab_xor_c <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then           -- rising clock edge
      ab_xor_c <= a_and_b xor c;
    end if;
  end process PROC_B;
end generate PIPELINE_EN_FALSE_GENERATE;
```

Comment: I prefer not to use variables as much as I can, I find them error prone very much. That's why I find your second code snippet is much useful to me. However, I did not understand why you used ```block``` construction. Can't we just write ```process``` inside ```generate``` like in the other answer by @user16145658?

Comment: Also, as you mentioned, I do not want to declare a signal that will not be used in the design, I know that it will probably optimized by the synthesis tools but I want to keep the code clean, that is why I write an ```if``` statement in the declaration space even though I know that it is illegal, I just wanted to better point out what I want.

Comment: I agree that variables should not be used to create flip-flops, and I will add that such code is advised against.

Comment: The `block` allow local declarations, which can then be conditional by the `generate`, like the intention of the conditional declaration in the original code.

Comment: So, as we do not need a local declaration in the below process, we do not have to use the ```block```, right?

Comment: Good and valid point, thanks.  I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

With a generic parameter for the pipeline depth:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is
  generic(
    depth: natural := 0
  );
  port(
    clk:   in  std_logic;
    rst_n: in  std_logic;
    a:     in  std_logic;
    b:     in  std_logic;
    c:     in  std_logic;
    z_out: out std_logic
  );
end entity example;

architecture rtl of example is

  signal a_and_b:  std_logic;
  signal ab_xor_c: std_logic_vector(0 to depth);

begin

  z_out <= ab_xor_c(depth);

  process(clk, rst_n) is
  begin
    if rst_n = '0' then
      a_and_b  <= '0';
      ab_xor_c <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      a_and_b     <= a and b;
      ab_xor_c    <= ab_xor_c srl 1;
      ab_xor_c(0) <= a_and_b xor c;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

And then, with `depth=2`:

```vhdl
use std.env.all;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example_sim is
end entity example_sim;

architecture sim of example_sim is

  signal clk:   std_logic;
  signal rst_n: std_logic;
  signal a:     std_logic;
  signal b:     std_logic;
  signal c:     std_logic;
  signal z_out: std_logic;

begin

  u0: entity work.example(rtl)
    generic map(
      depth => 2
    )
    port map(
      clk   => clk,
      rst_n => rst_n,
      a     => a,
      b     => b,
      c     => c,
      z_out => z_out
    );

  process
  begin
    clk <= '0';
    wait for 1 ns;
    clk <= '1';
    wait for 1 ns;
  end process;

  process
  begin
    rst_n <= '0';
    a     <= '1';
    b     <= '1';
    c     <= '1';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    rst_n <= '1';
    for i in 1 to 15 loop
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
      c <= not c;
    end loop;
    finish;
  end process;

end architecture sim;
```

Demo:

```sh
$ ghdl -a --std=08 example_sim.vhd
$ ghdl -r --std=08 example_sim --vcd=example_sim.vcd
simulation finished @21ns
$ open example_sim.vcd
```

[image: waveform]

Of course, if your data type (`T`) is more complex than a single `std_logic` you will need some extra work.

1. Define a vector type of your data type (`T_vector`).
2. Define a "*zero*" constant value for your base type (`T_zero`), this will be the value that enters on the left when shifting to the right.
3. Overload the `srl` operator for the `T_vector` vector type.

Example with a `T` type (not tested):

```vhdl
type T_vector is array(natural range <>) of T;
constant T_zero: T := <some zero value for your type>;
...
function "srl"(l: T_vector; r: natural) return T_vector is
  constant size: positive := l'length;
  constant tmp: T_vector(0 to size - 1) := l;
  variable res: T_vector(0 to size - 1);
begin
  if r = 0 then
    res := tmp;
  elsif r = 1 then
    res := T_zero & tmp(0 to size - 2);
  else
    res := (l srl 1) srl (r - 1);
  end if;
  return res;
end function "srl";
```

Comment: What if ```ab_xor_c``` is a vector? I tried a ```process``` inside a ```for-generate``` loop like this:
```
    PIPELINE_FOR      : for i in VECTOR_LENGTH - 1 downto 0 generate
 PROC_PIPELINE : process (clk, rst_n) is
 begin  -- process PROC_PIPELINE
     if rst_n = '0' then   -- asynchronous reset (active low)
  pipeline(i) <= (others => '0');
     elsif rising_edge(clk) then  -- rising clock edge
  pipeline(i) <= pipeline(i) srl 1;
     end if;
 end process PROC_PIPELINE;
    end generate PIPELINE_FOR;
```
However, now, I need to access to every last bit of each array row.

Comment: Also, pipeline is defined as:
```type pipeline_t is array (0 to HASH_OUT_LEN - 1) of std_logic_vector(PIPELINE_DEPTH - 1 downto 0);```
```signal pipeline : pipeline_t;```

Comment: See my updated answer for more complex types.

Comment: What if I want to declare the signal in ```block``` construction? How and where should I implement this function of yours?

Comment: Assuming the signal is defined as an ```array``` of ```std_logic_vector```.